# Angular ng new throwing error: npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Im trying to create a new angular project, after writing 'ng new project', it starts downloading but then gives me this error:

```
 Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.2: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142      
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to 
fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...EmGWKHtdKo\nmvJ5sCP6T'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-13T09_41_32_733Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
```

does anyone know whats wrong? tnx

Answer (score 2):

This happened due to you cache got corrupted. You need to clean your cache and re-install @angular/cli.

Open command prompt and run below commands.

```sh
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli
```